# What is the probability that all 3 copies of 1 card are drawn given you draw 9 cards from 27?

Tags: probability, summation, combinations

I'm playing board games and I'm trying to calculate the risk of a certain strategy. To do so I need this probability.

There are 9 different cards and 3 copies of each card for a total of 27 cards. What is the probability that when drawing 9 cards from 27 we get all 3 copies of at least 1 of the 9 unique cards?

Here's my current attempt at solving the problem but I think something is wrong:

n= number of identical cards being drawn = 3
k = total draws = 9
m = copies of each card = 3
a = number of unique cards being considered for n = 1
c = highest number of triples you can draw= 3
c*m = total cards = 27

f(a) = (m choose n)^a *((m(c-a)) choose (k-an)) = ((m(c-a)) choose (k-an))
g(a) = Sum(a=1 to 3)(-1)^(a+1)*(9 choose a)f(a)
(-1)^(1+1)(9 choose 1)*(3(9-1) choose 9-1(3))+(-1)^(2+1)*(9 choose 2)(3(9-2) choose 9-2(3))+(-1)^(3+1)(9choose3)(3(9-3)choose9-3(3))
=1211364-47880+84

1163568/(27 choose 9)~=.25

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Click "help" next to the comment field.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  to make your question more readable. Thanks, Joriki.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that all $3$ copies of $k$ particular cards are drawn is

$$
\frac{\binom{27-3k}{9-3k}}{\binom{27}9}\;,
$$

so by [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the probability that all $3$ copies of at least one card are drawn is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^3\binom9k(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\binom{27-3k}{9-3k}}{\binom{27}9}=\frac{9\binom{24}6-36\binom{21}3+84\binom{18}0}{\binom{27}9}=\frac{387856}{1562275}\approx0.25\;.
$$

Now that I’ve done the calculation, I can discern that this is exactly what you calculated. Next time, please use MathJax (see the link in the comments) to make your post legible.